# Calling a variable from another class PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm in the phase of learning OOP in PHP and i wanna know how to call a variable from another PHP class.

eg.

```
class first {
    public $var1 = 1;
}
```

I guess it's this way but i don't know how to continue:

> $first = new $first();

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
$first = new first();
echo $first->var1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it like this:

```
$first = new first();
$first->var1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For better way make like this:

```
class first {
    private $var1 = 1;
    function getVar(){
        return $this->var1;
    }

    function setVar($value){
         $this->var1 = $value;
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
class first {
    private $var1 = 1;
    function __get(){
        return $this->var1;
    }

    function __set($key,$value){
         $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

In this case you may try handling some exceptions.

Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: Using getter and setter functions is better OOP design, because it abstracts away internal representation from external access. For example, if you wrote a lot of code that depended on var1, but later decided to change the variable name to something else, then all the external code would break.

Comment: This is a question how you want to make the value accessible (e.g. read/write) and if you want to allow to change the value w/o the class noticing it. It's not better per-se, see as well http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html which has a provocative title but is about a lot of decisions that play a role.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Myname 
{
   public static $name='Your First Name';
}
class Mylast
{
   public static $last='Your Last Name';
}
class Fullname
{

     public static function staticValue() {
        return Myname::$name."--".Mylast::$last;
    }
}

print Fullname::staticValue() . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of the class:

```
$instance=new first();
```

and then you can access the variable from that instance:

```
$var=$instance->var1;
```

Note - there is no $ before the class name when you create an instance of it.